# Doubts about ODE's: Finding specific values.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm new to ODE's and I would like some guidance on the following questions:

> Consider the rate of change equation:
>
> $$\frac{dy}{dt} = 0.5y(y+2)(y-8)$$
>
> (a) For what values of $y$ is $y(t)$ increasing?
>
> (b) For what values of $y$ is $y(t)$ decreasing?
>
> (c) For what values of $y$ is $\frac{dy}{dt}$ neither positive or negative? What can we imply about the solution function $y(t)$?

I'm $1$ week into this class and all we do is group work since day $1$ as opposed to lecture, which I would've preferred. Aside from that, I believe that to set $\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$ and then solve for $y$, which I will get a cubic equation. So with these 3 roots, I will find where the graph is increasing and decreasing by plugging in points "close" to the approximations I found. Am I headed in the right direction? Any inquiries and suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Notice that $y$ is a factor, which leaves a quadratic factor.

Comment: I apologize I made a slight typo in the problem.

Comment: Find the values of $y$ for which $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=0$. That will divide the $y$-axis into four intervals. The sign of  $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ will be constant over each of those four intervals. Check its value for one value of $y$ in each of the four intervals and that will tell  you the sign of $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ over that entire interval.

Comment: Ah alright I'll give it a try and report back soon.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd say you're doing group work because the instructor is aware that not everyone has the same background, but that a bunch of folks in the class probably do in fact know how to do some of this more introductory stuff that is being covered. That's because it's really calculus: this is basically just asking you for the intervals of increasing and decreasing of a function.

Comment: That's actually what my professor somewhat mentioned yesterday Ian, but in the end, if she want's to stick to group work, so be it. In terms of the calculus aspect you just mentioned, that rang a bell immediately.

Comment: For part a, I got y = $(-2, 0) \cup (8, \infty)$.